# Converting arrow function to regular function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm going through Javascript 30 by Wes Bos.

I'm doing the AJAX type ahead course, and I'm sort of trying to limit the amount of ES6 I do on it, just for the sake of practice.

This is the finished version:

https://codepen.io/Airster/pen/KNYXYN

Note that as you type in a location, the searched value gets highlighted in yellow within the results.

Now the javascript that determines this is the displayMatches function:

```
var displayMatches = function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    var matchArray = findMatches(this.value, cities);
    var html = matchArray.map(function(place){
        console.log(this, place, "test");
        var regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
        var cityName = place.city.replace(regex, "<span class='hl'>" + this.value + "</span>");
        var stateName = place.state.replace(regex, "<span class='hl'>" + this.value + "</span>");
            return `
          <li>
            <span class="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span>
            <span class="population">${place.population}</span>
          </li>
            `;
    }).join("");
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}
```

The issue lies with the function variable `html`. Currently I have it as:

`var html = matchArray.map(function(place){...})`

This doesn't work, and I will get undefined in the results.

However, if I change it into an arrow function:

`var html = matchArray.map(place => {...})`

The function will run and the searched value will get highlighted.

Can someone explain why within this particular context, the arrow function works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to tell, must be the lexical scoping. Your this value probably isn't what you think.

Comment: try using a transpiler :p

Comment: even more fun would be to turn the outer function into an arrow function. As your `this.value` is only used, consider if you couldn't make it an argument of the method, which would make a lot more sense

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone explain why within this particular context, the arrow function works?

An arrow function (by definition) preserves the current lexical value of `this`.  A regular callback function does not.  So, when you use the regular callback function, you lose the proper value of `this` which your code depends on.

You can fix that by either using an arrow function which preserves the current scope value of `this` or by passing the optional `thisArg` to `.map()` as an argument right after the function.

From the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for `Array.prototype.map`, you can see the optional `thisArg`:

> ```
> var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
>     // Return element for new_array
> }[, thisArg])
> ```

So, to make your code preserve `this` without an arrow function, you can pass the `thisArg` to you call to `.map()`.

```
var displayMatches = function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    var matchArray = findMatches(this.value, cities);
    var html = matchArray.map(function(place){
        console.log(this, place, "test");
        var regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
        var cityName = place.city.replace(regex, "<span class='hl'>" + this.value + "</span>");
        var stateName = place.state.replace(regex, "<span class='hl'>" + this.value + "</span>");
            return `
          <li>
            <span class="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span>
            <span class="population">${place.population}</span>
          </li>
            `;
    }, this).join("");              // <== See the this argument passed here
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}
```

FYI, for completeness, there are actually six possible solutions here:

1. Pass the `this` argument to `.map()` as shown above
2. Use an arrow function (ES6 only)
3. Use `.bind(this)` with the callback function
4. Create a local variable `var self = this;` and reference `self` instead of `this`.
5. Use `let val = this.value` before the callback and then just use `val` inside the callback (code shown below).
6. Declare the `e` parameter to the event handler and use `e.target.value` instead of `this.value`, removing the need to use `this` at all.

Since `.map()` has the desired feature for `this` built-in, if you're not going to use an ES6 arrow function, then it makes the most sense to me to use the `.map()` argument, but all of these four solutions will work.

---

Looking at the details of what you're doing with `this` in your callback, you are only reading `this.value` so you could also just grab `let val = this.val` before the callback and just use `val` inside the callback too - eliminating the need to even use `this` at all.

```
var displayMatches = function(){
    let val = this.value;
    console.log(val);
    var matchArray = findMatches(val, cities);
    var html = matchArray.map(function(place){
        console.log(this, place, "test");
        var regex = new RegExp(val, 'gi');
        var cityName = place.city.replace(regex, "<span class='hl'>" + val + "</span>");
        var stateName = place.state.replace(regex, "<span class='hl'>" + val + "</span>");
            return `
          <li>
            <span class="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span>
            <span class="population">${place.population}</span>
          </li>
            `;
    }).join("");
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferred to pass in `this.value` as an argument to his function?

Comment: @Bergi But the way he uses the `this.value`, I don't see the need for the `this` scope at all, even the target container can be an argument. I am also looking to remove many different `this` values ;)

Comment: @Icepickle Oops, I misunderstood your comment, I thought you suggested to pass `this.value` (instead of `this`) as the second argument to the `map` function.

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, it might have been preferable to pass `cities`, `value` and `suggestions` as arguments to the function, however if you check the full code (in the linked codepen) you see that `displayMatches` is used as an event handler and `this.value` refers to the input value.

Comment: @Bergi That might be :) However, wrapping a function around the eventhandler that calls it, would make it more re-usable and could be a suggestion of how to solve his problem.

Comment: @Icepickle - The function is an event handler so we don't control what is passed to it and `this` is important to identify which element caused the event.  I added a new option to my answer at the end that just grabs `let val = this.value` before the callback and eliminates the need to access `this` at all inside the callback.  Another option.

Comment: @jfriend00 wouldn't the first parameter be contain the target then :) then there wouldn't be need for the this as we van grab it from the event argument

Comment: @Icepickle - Yes, one could use the `e` argument passed to the event handler as yet another solution to get to `e.target.value`.  That would be solution #6.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that unlike in an arrow function the `this` variable is being renewed for the new function. You should store the value of `this` in a new variable so you don't lose it in the function.

```
var displayMatches = function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    var that = this;
    var matchArray = findMatches(this.value, cities);
    var html = matchArray.map(function(place){
        console.log(that, place, "test");
        var regex = new RegExp(that.value, 'gi');
        var cityName = place.city.replace(regex, "<span class='hl'>" + that.value + "</span>");
        var stateName = place.state.replace(regex, "<span class='hl'>" + that.value + "</span>");
            return `
          <li>
            <span class="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span>
            <span class="population">${place.population}</span>
          </li>
            `;
    }).join("");
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the use of `this` variable. When you are using this inside a function, it will start to refer to the function itself rather than the one you intend it to.

Saving the value to another variable before use will do the trick for you.

```
const value = this.value;
const html = matchArray.map(function(place) { 
const regex = new RegExp(value, 'gi'); 
   ...
});
```

In JavaScript, **functions** are first-class **objects**, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. As a side effect of this, using the `this` variable inside a function (anonymous or otherwise) will result in it referring to itself rather than the *class object* which is common in Object Oriented Programming.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Lexical_this

**Arrow functions** do not bind `this` variable.

> An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the
>   enclosing execution context is used.

Here is how that will work out in your codepen. https://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/VMXyXB?editors=0010